# Question regarding the definition of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

> > **Definition**
> >
> > A binary structure $\left(G,\circ\right)$ is said to be a *group* if the following axioms are satisfied,
> >
> > 1. $(a \circ b )\circ c=a\circ (b\circ c)\ \forall a,b,c \in G$
> > 2. $\exists e \in G\mid \forall \ x \in G, e\circ x=x\circ e=x$
> > 3. $\exists \bar{a}\in G\mid \forall \ a \in G, a\circ \bar{a}=\bar{a}\circ a=e$
>
> Keeping the order of the axioms listed in the definition in mind, prove that among all possible orderings of these axioms, there exists exactly three orders which are acceptable as a definition of group. Which orders are not permissible and why?

I thought that ordering of the axioms didn't matter in the definition of group and so I am confused as to how to prove it. Any help?

Comment: You cannot start with $3.$, because we do not have $e$ then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what it means is if you were to show the axioms one by one to the reader he would have to understand them.

I think what the author wants you to say is axiom $2$ should always go before axiom $3$, since axiom $3$ talks about the identity.

Comment: But axioms are supposed to be independent, aren't they? Besides, if we state the axiom 3 as-"There exists a fixed element $e$ such that  for all $a \in G$ there exists a simultaneous solution of $a \circ x=e$ and $y\circ a=e$", what will be the problem? I think that this doesn't depend upon axiom 2.

Comment: It's not about the actual maths, it's about the order in which you would explain them. Stating axiom $3$ before axiom $2$ would not be understood by a student, since they do not know what $e$ is.

Answer (score 1):

What will happen if you put axiom 3 before axiom 2? Then you don't know what e is?